# Union de grafica de sympy y matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

Tengo un código ocupando sympy y matplotlib, sympy gráfica en una sola línea de código toda la región factible de las ineacuaciones; sin embargo, a la hora de querer graficar puntos exactos no encontre info, por lo que me desplacé a matplotlib, se que sympy ocupa matplotlib para graficar, ya que tiene un módulo llamado MatplotlibBackend, así que creí que era simplemente agregar un .extend() y ya, pero no fue así, alguna idea, consejo sobre como hacer esto, dejo adjunto código.

```
from sympy import *
x1 = Symbol('x')
x2 = Symbol('x2')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
y = sp.Symbol('y')

Funcion = 30000*x + 50000*y

x_vals = [0, 4, 0, 4, 2]
y_vals = [0, 0, 6, 3, 6]
Lista_Inecuaciones = [x>=0,y>=0, x<=4, y<=6, 3*x+2*y<=18]


#Grafica puntos en matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
puntos = ax.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, )


#combinacion para graficar en sympy
Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones = And(*Lista_Inecuaciones)
print(Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones)

#graficas
plot1 = plot_implicit(Lista_Combianda_inecuaciones, (x, -1, 10), (y, -1, 10), show=False)
plot2 = plot_implicit(sympify(Funcion), line_color="red", show=False)
plot1.extend(plot2)
plot1.extend(puntos) #linea que lanza error
plot1.show()
```